# Size of a empty Class & Derived Virtual Class

Tags: c++, class, oop, sizeof

1.Why is the size of Derived4 class shows 8 bytes ??

```
class Empty
{};
class Derived4 : virtual public Empty
{
    char c;
};
```

2.While the size of Derived2 class shows 4 byte ??

```
class Empty
{};
class Derived2 : virtual public Empty
{};
```

Comment: Padding to a word boundary? What happens if you add `char` fields?

Comment: This is implementation defined and thus pretty impossible to answer, but why would you care anyway?

Comment: that would be my bet. the vtable is causing the extra 4 bytes and sense a 'char' is only 1 byte you end up with a total of 5. the compiler is probably making it 8 bytes sense there on instructions for working with 8 byte values

Comment: You will note that there is a hidden pointer of type `int32_t(**)(...)` in the layout of `Derived4`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e2ceee351886e2f3f3845d4edc6da1f5-ad84d6ae4f014e55710df236f379b67c

Comment: As others have said, this is implementation defined. The standard only talks about minimum sizes for various types (eg, char is minimum 1 byte, but it could in principle be any higher number). What compiler are you using btw?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 10.0, But I still dont buy the comment which says vtable is causing 4 bytes, vtable will come in the picture when we have virtual functions isnt ?? or does it come sup when we drive a class virtual from base.., please clarify..anyone

Answer (score 5):

Note that `sizeof(any_class)` is implementation-defined.

But what actually happens in your case. Well, it is using `virtual` inheritance, most implementations use a hidden pointer to implement this feature which cost `sizeof(pointer)` bytes (the pointer is stored in the derived class itself), **plus** the sizeof all members *(if any)*,  **plus** padding *if necessary*, **plus** sizeof base class(es) (which could be reduced to zero, in case of empty base class, due to empty-base-optimization).

For more detailed answer, search for *"padding in C++"* on this site. You will find lots of topics on it.

Comment: Does Vptr & Vtable comes in the picture even in case of Virtual inheritance, I thought it comes in the picture Only when yiu have Virtual Fuunctions in your class bcz thats when you need Vtable.., Please clarify

Comment: @GeekPanther: Yes. One `vptr` for one virtual base. So if you have two virtual base classes, there will be two `vptr` and the size of the class will be computed accordingly. In case of empty base classes, the compiler may optimize this, so instead of two, it could have just one.

Comment: Then in that case what would be the contents of the Vtable, as in Case of Vfunction it contains address of Vfunctions, What Would be the contents of Vtable in case of Virtual Inheritence (Without any VFunc's) ??

Comment: @GeekPanther: I guess it should be empty, I'm not sure though, because compilers do lots of trick with each new release, nothing is permanent when it comes to compiler implementations. **Your program must not rely on those gory details**.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the size of `Derived4` class shows 8 bytes?
>
> ```
> class Empty
> {};
> class Derived4 : virtual public Empty
> {
>     char c;
> };
> ```

Under 32 bit machine g++ generates 1 byte for an empty class(inorder to represent class name in the memory). It is an intended behaviour.

You are inheriting `Empty` in `Derived4` as `virtual public` with result in creating `__vptr` variable in the class `Derived4` by the compiler as default. So the class `Derived4` will look something like this,

```
class Derived4 {
  void* __vptr; // 4 bytes
  char c; // 4 bytes as 1 char + 3 for structure padding
};
```

So the size of the above class in 8 bytes, I hope you agree with it.

---

> While the size of `Derived2` class shows 4 byte?
>
> ```
> class Empty
> {};
> class Derived2 : virtual public Empty
> {};
> ```

Here the same principle applies for empty class 1 byte and inheriting `Empty` in `Derived4` as virtual results `__vptr` variable inserted in the `Derived4` class. So, size of the `Dervied4` is `sizeof(void*)`; which is nothing but size of 4 bytes in 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to Saravanan statements that is true that Empty classes are non 0 bytes size but when used as base class then thanks to EBCO (Empty Base Class Optimization) the base class "overhead" is removed.